# Get user location while app is background in cordova android application

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, push-notification

I am developing location based android application using cordova (ionicframework+angularjs).So when app is in background i have to get the userlocation ,so that i can provide location based push notification.
Is that possible to run the app in background?. Please help

Comment: did u get any solution for this?

Comment: nop:),i didnt get any results

Comment: https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation

Answer (score 0):

In your requirement you need to use android Services.Otherwise you cannot run GPS Tracker in background(When app is in background). So if you need to run background service i think its not possible to do with ionicframework.Because its not native app development tool its only working with front end like browser base application. So you have to use native application development tool.